# How to close the app on Back Pressed in Log In fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I am using Navigation Components and Firebase authentication and I have two fragment **[A]** and **[B]**. where **A-> Log In** Fragment, **B-> User List**. When I successfully Logged-In from [A], I navigate to the fragment [B]. There is a Sign-Out button in [B] Fragment. when Sign Out button is pressed I signout from firebase and navigate to fragment [A]. But when I press back button then I am again navigating to fragment [B] instead of closing the app. I want to close the app if I am in Fragment [A] on back press.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear backstack and launch new top

[Learn More](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate)

try this

```
<action android:id="@+id/action_b_to_a"
            app:destination="@id/a"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/a"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this**
*implement the code your main activity*

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Log.e("TAG", "onBackPressed: "+getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() );
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1){
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }else {
        finish();
    }
}
```